# TFS + GIT Repo Alter Permissions Via Command Line

Tags: git, security, tfs

I am an administrator of a TFS 2013 server hosting some Git and TFVC repositories.

With TFVC I can use tf.exe to set permissions (tf permission) to certain groups and users and I made a script to help me do it.

How can I, via command line, set the permissions for a git project for both repository level, project level and branch level.

Is it even possible?

Comment: CodeWizard, I have made 5 questions here at StackExchange. This is one of them, 2 of them I answered myself, 1 is marked as duplicated and one did not helped me at all. I didn't get the purpose of this comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set permissions on a Git project, repository, or branch from the context menu or from the administration page in TWA, or by using the [TFSSecurity command line tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/TFS/administer/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd).

You can set all permissions for a project or repository. You can set Administer, Contribute, and Rewrite and destroy history (force push) permissions for a branch. Repositories and branches inherit permissions from assignments made at the project level.

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=vs.120)#Git

Comment: This looks promissing. I'll take a look. Thx